# RockShox SID not compressing

Tags: fork

I have a RockShox SID Race (not sure what year) that doesn't compress at all when I fully pump it with a floor pump, wondering if I have to take it apart and add oil or anything to make the fork compress?[image: Fork Air Chart][image: Fork]

This is the valve at the bottom? [image][image]

Comment: Forks need maintenance, yes. My RockShox Lyrik is only three years old, but it got significantly smoother again when I had it serviced recently. On another bike I had a Suntour fork that had become almost completely useless after two years (admittedly, I used it on rougher trails that it was designed for), and which I just replaced with a better fork.

Comment: Its Dual air, has a valve on the bottom and top.  Let the air out the bottom, and add about 50psi to the top, does it move (will be too soft for most riders)?   For accurate pressure you need a shock pump, especially for the lower valve that has a tiny air volume. Regardless, they can almost certainly do with a service as dual air will be at least 10 years old.

Comment: I found something that llooks like a valve, but when i tried to let air out, this yellow liquid also came out, is that the oil? Because I don't have any fork oil so i can't replenish the reservoirs. I put some more pics of the valve.

Comment: Yes, the lower valve is the negative air chamber.  Its is fork oil (a good sign as it means there is still some oil in the chamber).  Normally a little will come out with air, not enough to need replacing.    You might want to read https://cdn.sram.com/sites/default/files/techdocs/2001-2012_dual_air_tuning_guide_gen.0000000004160_rev_a.pdf

Comment: If the fork is not moving with low pressure, there is likely a problem with the damper on the right side.

Comment: @KeyinLiu If you don’t have fork oil, I think adding motor oil or even cooking oil might be better than no oil. How much came out? There isn’t much to begin with; you can’t afford to lose much.

Comment: Never done mine with the shock upside down, might be an issue - when right way up it should be no more than a few drops.

Comment: Just noticed the bike has no front brake, something else to get sorted.

Comment: just a few drops came out. The front brake thing is bc its a dirt jumper, so I didn't think that I needed a front brake

Comment: @MaplePanda How do I put oil into the fork? I've never serviced/setup a fork before.

Comment: Servicing instructions for a 2011 SID Dual Air here. https://cdn.sram.com/sites/default/files/techdocs/2011-sid-technical-manual.pdf  (Your will be very similar, check exact year for oil volumes and viscosity) .

Comment: im confused on how to remove the rebound and air knobs, as i have used a flashlight an there isnt anything at the bottom

Comment: @KeyinLiu Pretty sure I see a hex nut around the base of the air valve in the last photo you posted.

Comment: oh i see it too, but what about the rebound? the knob is hollow